# Сложность с постановкой запятой

Tags: пунктуация

**Я так понимаю, это наша ограда была(,) и дом.**

Мне кажется, запятая нужна. А как на самом деле?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что **надо поставить запятую**:

Я так понимаю, это наша ограда была, и  (=а также) дом.

Это присоединительный, а не соединительный союз (с учетом инверсии именной части сказуемого).

Comment: **Присоединяюсь** к мнению о том, что это **присоединительный** союз, и удаляю свой ответ. Полезные разъяснения о присоединительных членах предложения нашел тут: https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/